# Color of my href does not change on active

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an href, which has following code.

```css
   .calculate:active {
     background-color: red;
   }
   .calculate:hover {
     background-color: green;
   }
```

```html
<li class="calculate">
  <a href="calculate.html" style="font-size:18px">Calculator</a>
</li>
```

When I hold the click button on the calculator link then it changes color to red and when I release the click it comes back to green and then page loads to the specified calculate.html. When the page loads then the color of calculate href becomes red. Now the problem here is when I keep the click press on href it changes to red and when i actuallly click it then it changes back to green and waits till the page loads and changes back to red. I want it not to go back to green and be on red only when it is clicked.

Comment: you need to style the anchor when you want to style the anchor -.-

Comment: You are defining hover for the li, not the a. You need to style the anchor.

Comment: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wyb6d0j/)

Comment: *"When I hold the click button on the calculator link"* - What click button..?

Comment: @AbhinavPandey Ok... Then you can simply say the *link* BTW, *" I want it not to go back to green and be on red only when it is clicked."* - What does this mean..? Did you mean you want it to be red after it is clicked..?

Comment: *"waits till the page loads and changes back to red"* - does this mean, it has red color in a new page..? Then you must have applied that color in css for that page...

Comment: See on hover it is green and on pressing the link it becomes red but when I click the link then it becomes green and then loads the href target and then it becomes red!! I want it to not switch back to green after click and be red only

Comment: @AbhinavPandey *"on pressing the link it becomes red but when I click the link then it becomes green"* - What is the difference between *pressing* and *clicking*...? Anyway I added an answer from what I understood, hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

`:hover` should be defined before `:active`, not after. Also, use these pseudo-classes on a link, not on the list item.

```
.calculate a:hover{
   background-color:green;
 }
.calculate a:active{
   background-color:red;
 }
```

If you want to have it red after you click it, then use `:visited`. `:active` only makes it red at the time you click it. The `:visited` pseudo-class has to be added before the `:hover` class.

[Edit]

After your comments, I understood what you meant. You said that you get a transition from red to green immediately after the click, before the linked page gets loaded. You will always see this transition, unless you make the styles of `:hover` and `:active` equal.

Comment: See if you run the code snippet you will see that after click it returns to green and not red!!! thas what I want that it should be red after i have clicked it

Comment: @AbhinavPandey If you want to have it red after you click it, then use `:visited`. `:active` only makes it red at the time you click it.

Comment: Visited not working!! My problem statement is that After releasing the click href changes back to green and then when it goes to the target link it becomes red. I want to stop that transition to green after click and before loading to the new page.

Comment: @AbhinavPandey That's only possible if the style for `:hover` is exactly the same as for `:active`. If these styles are not equal, you will always see a transition.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want the link to stay red after clicking. For this, you can add a CSS class as shown below:

```js
var link = document.querySelector(".calculate");
link.onclick = function(){
  this.classList.add("clicked");
}
```

```css
.calculate:active {
   background-color: red;
}
.calculate:hover {
   background-color: green;
}
.calculate.clicked {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="calculate">
  <a href="#" >Calculator</a>
</li>
```